# Multiple column names in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am currently moving some data from a numpy array to a Pandas DataFrame so that I can refer to columns by their name, rather than their index. The problem that I have is that I would like to allow for multiple names to refer to the same column.

```
data = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('Sensor1231', 'Sensor4221', 'Sensor4673'))
```

Sensor4221, for example, is an accelerometer on the 5th level of a structure. I want to add an additional label so (eg. AccLevel5) so that I can refer to the column without having to remember an obscure sensor number.

Therefore, both of the following will provide the same output.

```
Accel = df['Sensor4221']
```

and

```
Accel = df['AccLevel5']
```

both give:

```
2
5
8
```

Comment: not possible bro. what you can do is use a `multiindex`

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

the dataframe is a wrapper on the numpy array.  You can assign another dataframe pointing to the same array to accomplish your goal.

```
data = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('Sensor1231', 'Sensor4221', 'Sensor4673'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values, df.index,
                   columns=('Sensor1231', 'AccLevel5', 'Sensor4673'))
```

---

```
df
```

[image]

```
df2
```

[image]

---

now reasign an element in `df` and see the change in `df2`

```
df.loc[1, 'Sensor4221'] = 999

df2
```

[image]